# Django not working on windows 10

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am trying to run django on windows 10. I installed virtual environment using:

```
python -m pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

then I entered the virtual environment:

```
mkvirtualenv project
```

Then I installed django using pip:

```
python -m pip install django
```

Everything went fine and i got a message that django was installed succesfully. After that I ran:

```
django-admin startproject mysite
cd mysite
```

Up to this point everything was going fine but then when I tried to start it using:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I got an error saying:

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and                  
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to 
activate a virtual environment?
```

Does anyone have experience with this error and if yes does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Is the virtualenv activated when you run this command?

Comment: Yes, it is activate.

Comment: do `pip freeze` to see what's installed.

Comment: Oh i see I should have installed django in virtual environment using pip install django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fixed it by entering the virtual environment using:

```
mkvirtualenv project
```

and then installing django with

```
pip install django
```

instead of

```
python -m pip install django
```